# Is there any way to add old version model instance to database at runtime using Entity Framework Core (code first)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let's say we create a class

```
public class Employee 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

We add and apply our first migration (of course we add DbSet to our ApplicationDbContext).

Then we add a new field to our class:

```
public class Employee 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Note { get; set; } // ***NEW FIELD***
}
```

We can add our second migration, just don't apply it.

Is there a way to add our new version of Employee to an old state database?

```
dbContext.Employees.Add(new Employee { FirstName = "John" });
```

This throws an error (and it should) about 'Note' column not being present in the database.

Just wondering is there any way to pass old verison of Employee or ignore that property at runtime?

Comment: There's the [NotMappedAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netcore-3.1) class, if you have properties that don't map to table fields. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @TiesonT. I want this property to be mapped to a table field, but only after second migration is applied. My code applies first migration (at runtime) then I need to seed that table with data obtained at runtime (but the model can be different from the first migration state). I don't know if that model was changed or not (it may be, it may be not). After seeding data I will apply all other migratons.

Comment: @vebvinas If your migration is prepared and pending then calling `applicationContext.Database.Migrate()` will apply it.

Comment: @HMZ I can't do that because second migration may be dependent of that seed data I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no way (at least that I know of) to add a new version entity into old version database I used:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employees] (FirstName) VALUES ({0})", "John");
```

This way I was able to accomplish my task.